# I 'm not connect my backend api with react-admin. Ocurred error:

Tags: react-admin

Warning: Missing translation for key: "The X-Total-Count header is missing in the HTTP Response. The jsonServer Data Provider expects responses for lists of resources to contain this header with the total number of results to build the pagination. If you are using CORS, did you declare X-Total-Count in the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header?"

Comment: You should add some details of what you did and show a minimal version of the code that produces this behaviour. And start doing some considerations about what could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

From the error it seems your API is not returning the X-Total-Count header. react-admin uses this header to create the pagination information (by default react-admin only requests and displays 10 records max per page, but it needs to know how many total records would have been returned had it not requested a maximum of 10, so that it can show you how many pages you can click through).

See the section "JSON Server REST" in the react-admin RestClients documentation page:

[JSON Server REST - X-Total-Count](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/blob/master/docs/RestClients.md)

Also, for an example implementation of the X-Total-Count header for an existing REST API, see the package loopback3-xTotalCount, which can be used to add the X-Total-Count header to a loopback3 REST API:

[loopback3-xTotalCount](https://github.com/kimkha/loopback3-xTotalCount)